# xampp phpmyadmin doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

2 messages occurring.

First one is:

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Second one is:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

But I set password to mysql by command line.

Answer (score 3):

Since you update mysql user password from commandline, you have to change your `config.inc.php` file. By default there won't be password given for `root` user in phpmyadmin config file.

You should change configuration in phpmyadmin config file to allow you to login using password.

There will be `config.inc.php` in phpmyadmin directory. In that:

**Method 1 : If you want phpMyAdmin to automatically login.**

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'write_here_password';
```

If you, configure this way It won't ask you for password to access phpmyadmin. It will use password from config file.

**Method 2 : If you want phpMyAdmin to show login screen and login manually.**

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

This way, it will present you with login screen of phpMyAdmin where you can type username `root` and password for that user (the one you set from commandline).

Comment: @moslehSamir Glad that it worked for you :) . If it solved your problem. Please consider Accepting as answer by clicking tick mark left hand side of the answer. See this to [learn how to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @moslehSamir, Would you please mark it as an answer? since your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Xampp you do not have to set a password. sure its better if you do but to test if everything is right, you should not set one untill everyting works.

by default its:

username: root

password: `leave this empty`

your error

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

says that you try to connect to mysql with a password but the system dont want a password.

either you have to edit the php config and set password usage or delete password via command line :)

Comment: Hey, Didn't you read the last line *but i set password to mysql by command line* ??

Comment: @Log1cツ yes i did. why ? he set up a password and the config file says no password and thats a conflict. did i get something wrong ? :)